# python bokeh: update scatter plot colors on callback

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bokeh

I only started to use Bokeh recently. I have a scatter plot in which I would like to color each marker according to a certain third property (say a quantity, while the x-axis is a date and the y-axis is a given value at that point in time).

Assuming my data is in a data frame, I managed to do this using a linear color map as follows:

```
min_q = df.quantity.min()
max_q = df.quantity.max()
mapper = linear_cmap(field_name='quantity', palette=palettes.Spectral6, low=min_q, high=max_q)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=get_data(df))

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
p.scatter(x="date_column", y="value", marker="triangle", fill_color=mapper, line_color=None, source=source)
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper['transform'], width=8,  location=(0,0))
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
```

This seems to work as expected. Below is the plot I get upon starting the bokeh server.

[image]

Then I have a callback function *update()* triggered upon changing value in some widget (a select or a time picker).

```
def update():
    # get new df (according to new date/select)
    df = get_df()
    # update min/max for colormap
    min_q = df.quantity.min()
    max_q = df.quantity.max()
    # I think I should not create a new mapper but doing so I get closer
    mapper = linear_cmap(field_name='quantity', palette=palettes.Spectral6 ,low=min_q, high=max_q)
    color_bar.color_mapper=mapper['transform'] 
    source.data = get_data(df)
    # etc
```

This is the closest I could get. The color map is updated with new values, but it seems that the colors of the marker still follow the original pattern. See picture below (given that quantity I would expect green, but it is blue as it still seen as < 4000 as in the map of the first plot before the callback).

[image]

Should I just add a "color" column to the data frame? I feel there is an easier/more convenient way to do that.

**EDIT**: Here is a minimal working example using the answer by bigreddot:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource, ColorBar, HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
z = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]



source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y=y, z=z))

#Use the field name of the column source
mapper = linear_cmap(field_name='z', palette=Spectral6 ,low=min(y) ,high=max(y))

p = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300, title="Linear Color Map Based on Y")
p.circle(x='x', y='y', line_color=mapper,color=mapper, fill_alpha=1, size=12, source=source)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper['transform'], width=8,  location=(0,0))
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips="@z", show_arrow=False, point_policy='follow_mouse'))
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

b = Button()

def update():
    new_z = np.exp2(z)
    mapper = linear_cmap(field_name='z', palette=Spectral6 ,low=min(new_z), high=max(new_z))
    color_bar.color_mapper=mapper['transform'] 
    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y, z=new_z)

b.on_click(update)

curdoc().add_root(column(b, p))
```

Upon update, the circles will be colored according to the original scale: everything bigger than 10 will be red. Instead, I would expect everything blue until the last 3 circle on tops that should be colored green yellow and red respectively.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that is a bug, feel free to open a GitHub issue.

That said, the above code does not represent best practices for Bokeh usage, which is: *always make the smallest update possible*. In this case, this means setting new property values on the existing color transform, rather than replacing the existing color transform.

Here is a complete working example (made with Bokeh 1.0.2) that demonstrates the glyph's colormapped colors updating in response to the data column changing:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource, ColorBar
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap

x = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
z = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]

#Use the field name of the column source
mapper = linear_cmap(field_name='z', palette=Spectral6 ,low=min(y) ,high=max(y))

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y=y, z=z))

p = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300, title="Linear Color Map Based on Y")
p.circle(x='x', y='y', line_color=mapper,color=mapper, fill_alpha=1, size=12, source=source)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper['transform'], width=8,  location=(0,0))
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

b = Button()

def update():
    new_z = np.exp2(z)

    # update the existing transform
    mapper['transform'].low=min(new_z)
    mapper['transform'].high=max(new_z)

    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y, z=new_z)

b.on_click(update)

curdoc().add_root(column(b, p))
```

Here is the original plot:

[image]

And here is the update plot after clicking the button

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the problem here is that the scale in your color map doesn't change. In that case I also have no problem. What I mean is that if my scale is originally 10-100 and in the next plot it becomes 1-10, markers with quantity 10 will be colored, say, in blue instead of red since according to the first map they would have been blue. I'll try to provide a working example.

Comment: To be more clear, upon call back the order of magnitude of the quantity might change considerably. Suppose in your example you take, instead of reversed(z), exp(z). Then almost all the circles would be red, which might not be very informative as (10 and 1000 would both be red but quite different). I would need the color bar to scale accordingly,  for example withs steps being instead of 2-4-...10, 2-16,...100. Hope it's more clear.

Comment: Added an edit with your working example modified to show what I mean. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, that appears to be a bug, but there is a way that works, and is also better practice in any case. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Oh this seems to work. Thanks, also for the tip on good practice. Replacing the color transform didn't feel right indeed. I don't know Bokeh well enough yet and in this case I missed the properties of mappers in general.